# How to pass a variable as an argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have several functions to make API calls to a application. Each function is set to return json format information. I declared another function to write the json output to a file to save on coding. I'm running into issues when trying to pass the function to make the API call as a argument. Is this even possible?

```
class ApiCalls(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 url='https://application.spring.com',
                 username='admin',
                 password='pickles',
                 path='/tmp/test/'):
        self.url = url
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.path = path

    def writetofile(self, filename, call):
        if not os.path.exists(self.path):
            os.makedirs(self.path)
        os.chdir(self.path)
        f = open(self.filename, 'w')
        f.write(str(self.call))
        f.close()

    def activationkey(self):
        credentials = "{0}:{1}".format(self.username, self.password)
        url = self.url + '/katello/api/organizations/1/activation_keys'
        cmd = ['curl', '-s', '-k',
               '-u', credentials, url]
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd)

x = ApiCalls()
x.writetofile('activationkey.json', activationkey())
```

Comment: You don't say what your "issues" are, which makes this harder to answer.  There is also missing context, I assume the `def ...(self...)` functions are part of a class named `ApiCalls`?

Comment: in the writetofile function I call filename and call variables, the call variable is the function being called. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @SkyVar Sounds like you want to simply do `filename(self)` and `call(self)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to pass functions around the same as other objects.

In your particular case you have confused the execution of the function from the function itself.

Consider `square` in the below example:

```
def square(val):
    return val * val
```

You are attempting to invoke it as

```
def func_of_1(func):
    return func  # You return the 'function' here

assert func_of_one(square()) == 1  # You call the function here
```

but you should be doing

```
def func_of_1(func):
    return func(1)   # Call the function with the argument here

assert func_of_one(square) == 1   # Pass the function here
```

To answer your very specific use case above - you should be doing

```
def writetofile(self, filename, call):
 ...
  f.write(str(call()))

   ...

x.writetofile('activationkey.json', activationkey)
```

Comment: Thx @Cireo with the class I had to use the class object to call the function when calling so it looks like this:

         def writetofile(self, filename, call):
        if not os.path.exists(self.path):
            os.makedirs(self.path)
        os.chdir(self.path)
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.write(call())
        f.close()
     x.writetofile('activationkey.json', x.activationkey)

Comment: Sorry can't figure out how to make it look like code in a comment...I fail

Comment: Yes, with the class you would need to use `x.activationkey`, since `activationkey` would no longer be defined.  I don't believe you can do block code in comments, don't worry =)